# Extract shapely polygon from matplotlib hexbin polycollection

Tags: geopandas, shapely, matplotlib

I'm trying to extract all the vertices of hexagons that are returned from `plt.hexbin`. I then want to eventually convert them to `shapely` polygons, so I can use them with `geopandas`. At the moment I can only seem to extract one polygon from the `PolyCollection` returned by `plt.hexbin`

Does anybody have any advice as to how to return the full grid of hexbins?

This example will reproduce my problem,

```
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
from matplotlib.patches import RegularPolygon


geoms = [Point(919.000, 533.500), Point(940.500, 528.500), 
 Point(937.000, 555.000), Point(889.000, 526.500), Point(898.000, 520.500)]

l = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':geoms})

y= np.array([ 533.500,  528.500,  555.000,  526.500,  520.500])
x= np.array([ 919.000,  940.500,  937.000,  889.000,  898.000])

f,ax=plt.subplots(1)
im =ax.hexbin(x,y, gridsize=(3,3), edgecolor='black')
l.plot(ax=ax, color='black', markersize=55)
```

Which produces this...

[image]

But when trying to extract the hexagons it produces a hexagon with the same position..

```
array_of_hexes=[]
for x,y in im.get_offsets():
    hexes = RegularPolygon((x, y), numVertices=6, radius= 5 )
    verts = hexes.get_path().vertices
    trans = im.get_transform()
    points = trans.transform(verts)
    array_of_hexes.append(Polygon(points))

gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':array_of_hexes}).plot(edgecolor='black')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Incase anyone faces a similar issue, the resolution is:

```
collection = plt.hexbin(x,y, gridsize=(5,5)
hex_polys = collection.get_paths()[0].vertices
hex_array = []
for xs,ys in collection.get_offsets():
    hex_x = np.add(hex_polys[:,0],  xs)
    hex_y = np.add(hex_polys[:,1],  ys)
    hex_array.append(Polygon(np.vstack([hex_x, hex_y]).T))

hex_grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':hex_array})
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add on to Sam Comber's amazing answer to add the hex data value as a geopandas column.  Might as well make it a function at the same time.

```py
# Imports
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon


# convert hex bins to geopandas with data column
def polygons_from_hexbins(collection):
    hex_polys = collection.get_paths()[0].vertices
    hex_array = []
    for xs,ys in collection.get_offsets():
        hex_x = np.add(hex_polys[:,0],  xs)
        hex_y = np.add(hex_polys[:,1],  ys)
        hex_array.append(Polygon(np.vstack([hex_x, hex_y]).T))

    counts = collection.get_array()
    return gpd.GeoDataFrame({'count': counts, 'geometry':hex_array})


# initial hexbin data
y= np.array([ 533.500,  528.500,  555.000,  526.500,  520.500])
x= np.array([ 919.000,  940.500,  937.000,  889.000,  898.000])
collection = plt.hexbin(x,y, gridsize=(5,5))
                        
# run conversion
hex_gdf = polygons_from_hexbins(collection)
hex_gdf.plot(column="count")
```

The final line outputs this geopandas plot:
[image]